# the totalAmount of increment and decrement

Tags: c#, increment, decrement

```
namespace rojak2.cs
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ArithmeticOperators();
        }

        static void ArithmeticOperators()
        {
            double totalAmount = 100;
            double result;

            Console.WriteLine("totalAmount is {0}", totalAmount);
            Console.WriteLine();

            result = totalAmount + 100;
            Console.WriteLine("totaAmount is {0}", result);

            result = totalAmount - 50;
            Console.WriteLine("totaAmount is {0}", result);

            result = ++totalAmount;
            Console.WriteLine("totaAmount is {0}", totalAmount);

            result = --totalAmount;
            Console.WriteLine("totaAmount is {0}", totalAmount);
        }
    }

}
```

my question is why the last output of result is 100 not 99? it should be decreased from 100 not 101. I dont quite get it.

Comment: Having a namespace name ending with `.cs` is really weird, because namespaces don't have to (and shouldn't!) map one to one with files.

Answer (score 2):

because of preincrement.  Variable value gets incremented before its value gets copied to the result. So result will have 101 as an outcome of preincrement and also for decrement - it subtracts one first and then copies value, hence you get result as 100.

Answer (score 1):

> It should be decreased from 100 not 101

Why? You can *tell* that `totalAmount` is 101 before this statement, as that's the output of the previous line!

Let's look at how the variables change over the course of the code:

```
double totalAmount = 100;
double result;
result = totalAmount + 100;

// totalAmount = 100; result = 200

result = totalAmount - 50;

// totalAmount = 100; result = 50

result = ++totalAmount;

// totalAmount = 101, result = 101

result = --totalAmount;

// totalAmount = 100, result = 100
```

I suspect it's the prefix increment/decrement that's confusing you.

This statement:

```
result = ++totalAmount;
```

Is basically equivalent to:

```
totalAmount = totalAmount + 1;
result = totalAmount;
```

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
result = ++totalAmount;
```

Changes not only `result`, but `totalAmount` too; That's why on last line, it's 101, not 100